# updating module faced Error Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just faced this problem after updating Gradle

`Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`

App Gradle :

```
compileSdkVersion 27

minSdkVersion 17

targetSdkVersion 27

dependencies {
    implementation project(':abringlibrary')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Module Gadle :

```
compileSdkVersion 27

minSdkVersion 17

targetSdkVersion 27

dependencies {
    implementation project(':abringlibrary')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Build Error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: To which Gradle version have you updated?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

Comment: @Anatolii how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you also share `the compiler error output for details.`?